# Can I delete the Terminalted Instance by AWS EC2?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have created one AWS EC2 ubuntu instance to host my backend.
I mark it as Terminated. 
Can I delete the Terminated Instance by AWS EC2?
Or the instance is stay in my dashboard.
Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quick Answer: After terminattion, it will be deleted automatically after some time.

- Terminating your instance is essentially deleting it, it will take
  some time to get reflected on your dashboard (meaning it won't appear
  on your instance list table)
- There is no use of terminated instances.
- Once you terminated your instances, it means you have completely lost
  that particular instance.

But during the time of creation of your instance if have you had enabled the option called Protect against accidental termination. Then you will not be able to terminate without disabling this option.

But in your instance table if the Instance State column has the value terminated it means your instance is deleted and you can no longer use it.

*Note By default, Amazon EC2 deletes the Amazon EBS root device volume at instance termination. Additional volumes that were attached when the instance launched and any volumes that were attached after instance launch persist. For more information, see Preserving Amazon EBS Volumes on Instance Termination in the Amazon EC2 User Guide for Linux Instances.*

Answer (score 5):

You really don't need to delete the instance.

From [Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/terminating-instances.html)

After you terminate an instance, it remains visible in the console for a short while, and then the entry is automatically deleted. You cannot delete the terminated instance entry yourself.